# Namenode service unstable in hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I have setup a hadoop cluster with 1 namenode and 1 datanode (using  hadoop version 1.2.1) but when I start both nodes, the namenode service dies (does not appear in list of running java processes) within seconds (datanode service remains up). Can anyone please help me with the reason?

I have tried - removing the temporary files and then re-formatting the namenode before starting the namenode again but that did not help.

I have attached the screenshots of my core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml entries for both my namenode  and datanodes.

Please let me know the reason if possible.

[hadoop version and location screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQsjO.png)

[core-site.xml of namenode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvSLI.jpg)

[hdfs-site.xml of namenode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiHbf.jpg)

[No errors in formatting namenode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG1ub.jpg)

[jps listing and unstable namenode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOmEn.png)

[hdfs-site.xml of datanode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPKja.jpg)

[namenode log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGG75.jpg)

Comment: You have two different hosts, one configured to run `namenode` and other to run `datanode`, correct? Can you post the namenode logs? It will be good if you can replace these screenshot links with inserted images!

Comment: @franklinsijo : Yes , Thats right . I have attached a screenshot of the content of the file shown when I run the command : "hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode" (logs to /var/log/hadoop/root/hadoop-root-namenode-subhadip_namenode.out)

Comment: @franklinsijo : Since I am a new contributor , My picture attachments are not being directly embeded, they are automatically being converted to links

Comment: That is the out file, the log file should be this `/var/log/hadoop/root/hadoop-root-namenode-subhadip_namenode.log`

Comment: @franklinsijo:  Thank You so much for pointing to the right direction :-)

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the error message in the log . it said "incompatible hdfs URI no host" - which was due to an underscore ("_") character in my hostname ("subhadip_namenode"). I have rectified the error and the namenode is stable now ! :-)